# Class load in main class loader depends to class load in child class loader

Tags: java, classloader, urlclassloader

Hi i have a class load in main classloader who depends to a class load in a child classloader how can i do ?
I have heared about parent-last classloader but i don't fully understand how it's working and if that can solved my problems.

Comment: Please provide more details about your current code, what you have tried and why it is not working.

Comment: Basically your question is too broad. It _might_ help if you could put up a [mcve] and show code, instead of explaining what your code is supposedly doing or not doing. But just from a logical perspective, your idea sounds wrong. When the root depends on it, it can't be on a child.